# How to force Typesafe Activator to listen 0.0.0.0:8888

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-stack, typesafe, typesafe-activator

I recently installed Typesafe Activator to a VM. Applications created by activator can be accessed after port forwarding, but Activator seems to listen localhost. How to change this to WAN?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like setting system properties `http.address` and `http.port` will now do this job, e.g.

```
./activator -Dhttp.address=0.0.0.0 -Dhttp.port=80
```

Would launch Activator on a WAN on port 80 (assuming matching permissions, etc).

Answer (score 3):

It is hardcoded right now and there's no way to change short of recompiling from source. https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/blob/master/ui/app/activator/UIMain.scala#L99

Maybe we could prefix this with `if (System.getProperty("http.address") == null)`
File an issue on github?

**Update: this is now fixed so that -Dhttp.address works** (and above source link no longer goes to the right place)

Answer (score 2):

Base on Michael Nash's answer, but should be

> ./activator ui -Dhttp.address=0.0.0.0 -Dhttp.port=80

for version 1.2.10