# Java Play activator crashes after a minute

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am running Activator 1.2.3 on an Ubuntu VM with Oracle Java 8 (I had the same problem with Java 7) installed. I was attempting run Java Play server to train/develop on.

It starts up successfully, and I can even access the UI in my browser, but after a minute or so regardless of whether I do anything or not, the Activator crashes/stops with the following error:

```
/opt/activator/activator ui -Dhttp.address=0.0.0.0
Checking for a newer version of Activator (current version 1.2.3)...
... our current version 1.2.3 looks like the latest.
Found previous process id: 16189
FOUND REPO = activator-local @ file:/opt/activator-1.2.3/repository
Play server process ID is 16442
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8888
java.lang.RuntimeException: Web server never started!
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at activator.UIMain.checkAlive$1(UIMain.scala:164)
        at activator.UIMain.waitForServerStartup(UIMain.scala:169)
        at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:115)
        at activator.UIMain.run(UIMain.scala:87)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.RuntimeException: Web server never started!
[info] application - onStop received closing down the app
[warn] application - AppManager onApplicationStop is disabled pending some 
refactoring so it works with FakeApplication in tests
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the CheckAlive method being called maybe failing because it's attempting to test against the 0.0.0.0, etc IP that was specified because I wanted it to listen on all IP's not just localhost (see [How to force Typesafe Activator to listen 0.0.0.0:8888](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234466/how-to-force-typesafe-activator-to-listen-0-0-0-08888)). I set the IP parameter to the external IP of the VM (10.0.2.15) and now it seems stable.

```
/opt/activator/activator ui -Dhttp.address=10.0.2.15
```

For automation purposes, you can also do the following:

```
IP_ADDRESS=`ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`
/opt/activator/activator ui -Dhttp.address=${IP_ADDRESS} -Dhttp.port=8888 &
```